# Ruby blocks - yield {puts} vs. puts yield

Tags: ruby

While browsing Rubymonk tutorial, I've noticed something odd.

Although the following two snippets produce the same output, I'm wondering if there are some ninja-hidden implications of using one or another. Is it just the flexibility or should I be cautious about something?

```
def foo
 yield
end
foo { puts "antyhing"  }
```

vs.

```
def foo
 puts yield
end
foo { "antyhing"  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first snippet:

- the method yields to the block
- the block prints the string `"anything"`
- the method returns the return value of the blocks, which is the return value of `puts`, which is `nil`

In the second snippet:

- the method yields to the block
- the block returns the string `"anything"`
- the method prints the return value of the block
- the method returns the value of `puts`, which is `nil`

Having said that, it depends on what you want to achieve with the block the methods yields to.

In the first snippet, it is more about yielding the control to the block and the block does whatever it needs to do. The return value might not be relevant, or it might be relevant as the return value of the method.

In the second snippet, the block serves as a way to calculate a value that will then be used by the method.

To illustrate the two cases, here's two examples:

```rb
def on_create
  yield created_user
end

on_create do |user|
  send_welcome_email(user)
end
```

```rb
def send_email(address)
  body = yield
  EmailService.deliver(address, body)
end

send_email('alice@example.com') do
  "Hello Alice, ..."
end
```